# Can't figure out Oracle update query involving two different tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update

The SQL relation between two table is like below:

```
CREATE TABLE meve_hall (
  hallNo NUMBER, 
  hallName varchar(20), 
  seatCapacity NUMBER, 
  PRIMARY KEY(hallNo)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE meve_student (
  stuId NUMBER, 
  name varchar(20), 
  dept varchar(20), 
  hallNo NUMBER, 
  PRIMARY KEY(stuId), 
  FOREIGN KEY(hallNo) REFERENCES meve_hall(hallNo)
)
```

Now the question is:

> Change the hallName= 'Ziaur' of those students who is in dept='CSE'

Comment: What have you tried so far? and please provide some sample data and your expected output to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can write an `UPDATE` statement `WHERE hallNo IN` and a subquery to get the `hallNo` based on `dept = 'CSE'`.

```
UPDATE meve_hall SET hallName = 'Ziaur'
WHERE hallNo IN (SELECT hallNo FROM meve_student WHERE dept = 'CSE')
```

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ta0BV7_i).**

Comment: Why wouldn't you then accept/upvote the answer, @Balay?

Comment: I assume the OP doesn't know how to. @Balay, please read: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)